# Can't $.parseJSON() when string holds src="" or id="" attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I can use $.parseJSON() when doing this:

```
var myString = '{ "Header": "<p>some content</p>"}';
var modelJsonObject = $.parseJSON(myString);
```

But not when `"Header"` value holds `src=""`, `id=""` ect. like below:

```
var myString = '{ "Header": "<p><img src=\"http://placehold.it/50x50\" style=\"line-height: 1.3; width: 50px;\"><br></p>"}';
```

Then I get a SyntaxError: Unexpected token in my console

What to do?

Comment: The example you says works will throw a syntax error. Please show us a real example. It probably has something to do with improperly escaped quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since JSON strings start and end with quotation marks (`"`), any such quotation marks *within* a string must be escaped, like so: `\"` Thus a JSON string consisting of just a quote would be `"\""`.

But then there's JavaScript's syntax. A string written as `'\"'` in JS results in the string `"`. (Try `console.log('\"')`.) Since backslashes have special meaning in JS, they have to be escaped.

The sum of the above is that a JSON string consisting of just a quote written in JS would be:

```
'"\\""'
```

Conclusively, your string would have to be written like so:

```
var myString = '{ "Header": "<p><img src=\\"http://placehold.it/50x50\\" style=\\"line-height: 1.3; width: 50px;\\"><br></p>"}';
//             1            2              3
```

1. Is the start of the *JavaScript* string.
2. Is the start of a *JSON* string, *within* the JS string.
3. Is a quote *within* the JSON string.

---

Note that using single quotes in JS saves us from having to escape the double quotes for *JS*, but the JSON syntax still has to be correct. If we use double quotes for the string, then we end up with this rather funny-looking thing:

```
"{ \"Header\": \"<p><img src=\\\"http://placehold.it/50x50\\\" style=\\\"line-height: 1.3; width: 50px;\\\"><br></p>\"}";
```

Where `\\\"` is a JS-escaped backslash (`\\`) followed by a JS-escaped quote (`\"`), resulting in a JSON-escaped quote.